# IE8 Showing a divider between images

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Within my site I have four images set into a square with the following code

```
        <div id="tempo_main">

        <div id="tempo_content">
            <div style="text-align: center;z-index: 3;position: absolute;right:350px; left:350px; top: 305px; overflow: hidden;"><img alt="PW" src="/media/1001/prospectLogo.jpg" width="319" height="115" /></div>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="black">
    <tr>    
        <td align="right"><a href="/ourwines/whites.aspx" ><img src="media/1012/intro_3_Fade.gif" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='media/1013/intro_3_Original.gif'" onmouseout="this.src=src='media/1012/intro_3_Fade.gif'" height="250" widht="357" /></a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="AwardsAccolades.aspx"><img src="media/1008/intro_1_Fade.gif"  border="0" onmouseover="this.src='media/1009/intro_1_Original.gif'" onmouseout="this.src=src='media/1008/intro_1_Fade.gif'" height="250" width="357" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td align="right"><a href="/winery.aspx"><img src="media/1014/intro_4_Fade.gif" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='media/1015/intro_4_Original.gif'" onmouseout="this.src=src='media/1014/intro_4_Fade.gif'" height="250" width="357" /></a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="#"><img src="media/1010/intro_2_Fade.jpg" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='media/1011/intro_2_Original.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='media/1010/intro_2_Fade.jpg'" height="250" width="357" /></a></td>
        <td height="25"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

I am working on someone else's old code for a site that was done more than 5 years ago! Everything works on chrome but just IE8 renders this gap in between the images.

The image below displays an example of the problem! The top browser is IE8 and the bottom browser is chrome. Notice the line dividing the two images on top from the two images on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Do they have `display: block` applied to them? If not, try that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is a margin being added by the browser. Trying removing any padding or remove any borders from the image. I think some versions of IE added a border to images.